# C# OOP concepts: is inheritance from Control class the right way?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, inheritance

My question is about the right way of code writing. I use C# Winforms.
I created an instance of Control class (anyone available in designer), for example Panel class, set some properties of this object, subscribed events, wrote event handlers, etc. But usually I do this by next way: I create my CustomPanel class inherited from Panel and white above code (setting properties, subscribing events, event handlers) in CustomPanel class. So, when I want to use Panel with my setting and functionality, I can drag and drop CustomPanel object from designer. Is this a right way or interitance from Control classes isn't a good idea? Maybe I should create my own class (not inherited) contains Panel settings and bind it to Panel?

Comment: This is *strongly* encouraged in Winforms.

Comment: @Hans: _This_ is referring to the last sentence in the question:  Create a helper class to do the decorating etc.., right? I tend to agree, unless one really wants to have it already working in the designer.

Comment: No, deriving your own class from a base Winforms class, like Panel or Control, is very strongly supported.  Too many programmers get lost in a UserControl which can only provide encapsulation, usually because they think they need to get started by using the designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use decorators when possible

Using Visual inheritance with the windows form designer is very very buggy, a lot of times the designer doesn't work and on top of that it **never** works when your controls are in a 64 bit assembly
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967050

Answer (score 0):

I would rely on [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) when making the decision.  If what you're making ia a Panel in spirit, then it's OK to inherit (I feel it's OK).

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Forms there are very limited capabilities to modify the controls(You could try [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where are more ways to achieve such modification).

1) In WinForms you usually either end with enormous amount of event handlers:

```
winFormsControl.OnSomethingChanged += new delegate(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)
    {
        WinFormsControl control = (WinFormsControl)sender;

        control.Property = value;
        // ...
    };

winFormsControl.OnSomethingOtherHappened += this.Handle_WinFormsControl_OnSomethingOtherHappened;
```

2) or build your own derived class if you have to add a lot of your properties and events or some methods to override like:

```
public class MyCustomPanel : Panel
{
    //Constructor
    public MyCustomPanel()
    {
        base.Layout += this.OnBaseLayout;
        ...
    }

    // Overriden methods(i am not sure if there could be any)
    public override void SomeVirtualMethod() {...}

    // Custom members
    public CustomLayoutMode LayoutMode { get; set;}

    public event EventHandler CustomLayoutCompleted;
}
```

3) Creating your own UserControl derived class is an option too.

4) Also you could try to wrap the existing control in a custom control derived directly from the Control:

```
public MyCustomControl : Control
{
    private Panel WrappedPanel;

    public MyCustomControl()
    ...
}
```

But I am a bit unsure about the way how you will paint inside your wrapper(but it is probably possible, just my WinForms are rusty).

Nonetheless most of the considered scenarios will be non-ideal - usually we need original properties and events of the Panel to be in Control's interface and no one likes boilerplate code.

The simplest way to avoid such problems is to inherit. No one says that it is the best. Especially when you will have to combine some hard-coded behaviours of custom controls into one.

Comment: I preferred 2nd way, it seems code looks more clear and encapsulated. I hope that is ok...